# Tracking cycles while adding random edges to a sparse graph

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm, traversal, graph-traversal

Scenario:  I have a graph, represented as a collection of nodes (0...n).  There are no edges in this graph.

To this graph, I connect nodes at random, one at a time.  An alternative way of saying this would be that I add random edges to the graph, one at a time.

I do not want to create simple cycles in this graph.

Is there a simple and/or very efficient way to track the creation of cycles as I add random edges?  With a graph *traversal*, it is easy, since we only need to track the two end nodes of a single path.  But, with this situation, we have any number of paths that we need to track - and sometimes these paths combine into a larger path, and we need to track that too.

I have tried several approaches, which mostly come down to maintaining a list of "outer nodes" and a set of nodes internal to them, and then when I add an edge going through it and updating it.  But, it becomes extremely convoluted, especially if I *remove* an edge in the graph.

I have attempted to search out algorithms or discussions on this, and I can't really find anything.  I know I can do a BFS to check for cycles, but it's so so so horribly inefficient to BFS after every single edge addition.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution I came up with while in the shower.

What I will do is maintain a list of size n, representing how many times that node has been on an edge.

When I add an edge (i,j), I will increment list[i] and list[j].

If after an edge addition, list[i] > 1, and list[j] > 1, I will do a DFS starting from that edge.

I realized I don't need to BFS, I only need to DFS from the last added edge, and I only need to do it if it at least has potential to be in a cycle (it's nodes show up twice).

I doubt it is optimal.. maybe some kind of list of disjoint sets would be better.  But this is way better than anything I was thinking of before.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep track of the connected components of your graph, you can test for every edge you insert whether the involved nodes are already in the same component. If they are, then the edge you are inserting will introduce a cycle to your graph.

Have a look at this post that seems to give some good references on how to do this: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/is-there-an-online-algorithm-to-keep-track-of-components-in-a-changing-undirecte